# looking for a stable gaming custom ROM for Xperia Neo V

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Gingerbread seems to be better in gaming on my device. I will really appreciate it if someone could point me to a stable custom rom built with gaming in mind

Comment: Hummm.... this is *off-topic* as in asking for recommended ROMs... You did say, *Gingerbread seems to be better in gaming on my device* and yet asking for a stable rom....?

Comment: True that Gingerbread is great for gaming but stock roms aren't as 'feature packed' as custom roms. However custom roms sometimes sacrifice stability for bleeding edge features hence my quest for a stable custom rom